# Why do we care if a set forms a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, change-of-basis

I am taking an advanced linear algebra course and am once again confused by a lot of the concepts. I understand that the definition of a basis is a set of vectors that spans the vector space and is linearly independent. Can anyone provide any intuition on why this matters?

I can visualize (kind of) what it means for a set to span a vector space, and I understand (from regression analysis) why it is important that vectors are linearly independent, but I don't really understand why it matters if they are both, ie why it matters if they form a basis.

For reference I am an undergraduate interested in statistics and data analysis. I have taken courses in mathematical statistics, regression analysis and am currently enrolled in time series analysis. I am somewhat familiar with PCA. Any intuition that can be provided through any of those lenses would be much appreciated.

Comment: If a set of vectors forms a basis for a vectorspace, then every vector in the vector space can be expressed in terms of the vectors in the basis.

Comment: A basis of a vector space is like a pillar of a building. Each vector is expressed by a finite number of vectors. As every  3D-coordinate can be expressed with $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$

Comment: PCA is the result of a change of the basis of applied to your co-variance matrix.  You are isolating the single factor that has the most influence on your data.  And then the next most significant factor that is independent from the first.  and proceeding down the line

Comment: @DougM Thank you!!! That is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I thought it would have some relevance to PCA. If you had posted this as an answer I would "select it as my answer."

Comment: @agra94 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We care because mathematicians are inherently lazy, and having basis usually enables you to check things for a very small number of cases while being able to generalize to the whole space...

Take linear transformations as an example. If you know how a linear transformation behaves for the basis vectors, you automatically know how it behaves for the whole space.

Comment: This wound up being very helpful today in differential geometry. Thank you.

Comment: @agra94 glad I could help. If you issue was solved, consider accepting any of the answers. If your issue was *not* solved, please let me know in what way I can help.

Answer (score 2):

This matter because we need a basis to can express in a unique way all the vectors of a given vector space.

Indeed, for example, when in $\mathbb{R^3}$ we write that a vector is $\vec w=(a,b,c)$ what we mean is that

$$\vec w=a\vec v_1 + b\vec v_2 +c\vec v_3$$

where $\vec v_1$,$ \vec v_2$ and $ \vec v_3$ are the vectors of the choosen basis.

As an intuitive geometric argument you can think that in a 3D space you need a reference system (that is a basis) to can identify points i.e. vectors in the space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keep your geometric intuition at hand.

How do we introduce a co-ordinate system in, say, a plane? We decide about the origin, *then* we put together two axis (usually orthogonal, but not always), and then, suddenly, every point is described via two co-ordinates, and you can calculate! In effect, you've set up two vectors (say $\vec{OX}$ and $\vec{OY}$) and you are representing points (say $A$) using the decomposition of the vector $\vec{OA}=x\vec{OX}+y\vec{OY}$.

Now, why is it that for every point $A$ we have uniquely determined $x$ and $y$ co-ordinate? It is precisely because the vectors $\vec{OX}$ and $\vec{OY}$ make up a basis of the vector space of planar vectors.

Generalising this example, I think this is the bottom line:

- A basis lets you set up a "co-ordinate system"; say, $\bf{e}=(\bf{e_1},\bf{e_2},\ldots\bf{e_n})$ is a basis of a vector space $V$: now every vector $\bf{v}\in V$ can be represented using "co-ordinates" $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $\bf{v}=x_1\bf{e_1}+x_2\bf{e_2}+\ldots+x_n\bf{e_n}$ (this is because $\bf{e}$ spans the whole $V$), and those co-ordinates are *uniquely determined* (this is because $\bf{e}$ is a linearly independent system).
- Having the co-ordinates, we can now calculate in $V$ using ordinary calculation in the base field.

Comment: This is also my point of view on the main point for a basis.

Comment: This is a good reason, but the consequence of it in [RGS’ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2621430/265466) is IMO more compelling: a *lot* of interesting and important operators are linear and having a basis lets you simplify how you work with them.

Answer (score -1):

There is an important theorem:

All Basis have the same size.

This allows one to define the dimension of a vector space as this size.

The dimension is the fundamental invariant of a vector space.